# How does assembly handle large amounts of variables?

Tags: variables, assembly, memory, cpu-registers

Let's say I have compiled a program that juggles roughly 1000 variables around. The number of registers in the CPU is far fewer than this. How can the compiled code keep track of all these variables?

I am not sure I understand how assembly handles memory. Does it create chunks in memory for each variable which it can access later? How do the registers play a role in this when data needs to be transferred?

Comment: Stack space for local vars, static storage for global/static vars.  Registers for temporary 
copies of those, with some functions keeping some variables in registers for whole loops or across multiple statements.  (Register allocation is usually done based on graphs of variable lifetimes and how many times they're accessed.)

Comment: Related / potential duplicates: [How do compilers store hundreds of variables in only a few registers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30720536) / [How to store multiple variables with only a finite amount of registers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33246674) / [How is it known that variables are in registers, or on stack?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32298644) / [How Long Should A Variable Be Stored In A Register?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39714856)

Answer (score 1):

The assembly language uses registers and memory to manage variables. Registers provide quick access to data, whereas memory is used for larger storage requirements. The stack and data segments are useful tools for managing variables, and compilers help to optimize their use.